# Error running JUnitWeb Test on Method setup

Tags: java, spring, junit, log4j, dbunit

I have a Spring application,
and I've created this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(locations = {
        "classpath:testDatabaseContext.xml",
        "classpath:testServicesContext.xml",
        "classpath:backoffice-servlet.xml"
})
public class UserControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    void setup(WebApplicationContext wac) {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }
..
}
```

but when I start the test I got this error:

```
rg.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'com.pastis.UserControllerTests':
  1. Method setup() should be public
  2. Method setup should have no parameters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example:

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyWebConfig.class)
public class CustomerControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup () {
        DefaultMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac);
        this.mockMvc = builder.build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserController () throws Exception {
        ResultMatcher ok = MockMvcResultMatchers.status()
                                                .isOk();

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/customers");
        this.mockMvc.perform(builder)
                    .andExpect(ok);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I explain the output of the exception:

1. Add the modifier public to your method setup, otherwise JUnit can't invoke it
2. Remove the parameter from the method, @Before, @After and such don't allow parameters.

How to setup MockMvc correctly is another question. Recent Spring and additional annotations regarding web scope initialization and -behavior leave the scope of this answer. (This also requires more clarification, for example which JDK, which Spring or Spring Boot… XML configuration, dbunit and JUnit 4 suggest a legacy context.)